# Issue with NSDateFormatter, while NSDate from string with time only

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am facing wired issue with `NSDateFormatter`.

Following is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mma"];
NSString *currentHours = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Hours: %@", currentHours);
```

If the device setting set to show time in 12 hours (i.e. with AM & PM) following is the output:

```
Hours: 12:40PM
```

If the device setting set to show time in 24 hours output is:

```
Hours: 12:41
```

This also affecting my other code.

```
NSDate *open = [formatter dateFromString:@"08:00am"];
NSDate *close = [formatter dateFromString:@"05:00"];
```

If the device setting set to show time in 24 hours then both date objects are `nil`. In a case of 12 hours clock setting its working fine.

If any one has solution for same please let me know.

Comment: In 24 hr format there is no AM or PM

Comment: I know that. But my date formator is @"hh:mma".

Comment: i think below answer will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the formatter locale to:

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```

However, note that this will force `a` to English localization "AM"/"PM". Many languages (including mine) don't use a suffix to denote "AM"/"PM".

This is a rather annoying bug but if you care about localization, you should respect user settings and don't force 12h vs 24h time.

Ideally, you should just set the style of the formatter and let it use the system settings:

```
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the locale of the formatter explicitly to `en_US_POSIX`

```
formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
```